# Finding basis of coefficients satisfying system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, summation

**Setup:** Let $C_{i,j}$ denote coefficients which are symmetric in their indices---i.e., $C_{ij}=C_{ji}$.  These coefficients are required to satisfy the following relation for all $m\in \mathbb{Z}^+$ and $n\in\mathbb{N_0}$,

\begin{align}
\sum_{j\le m}\frac{m!}{j!(m-j)!}C_{n+j,m-j}=0\label{relation}\tag{*}.
\end{align}
Note the summation index is taken to be over non-negative integers $j\in \mathbb{N}_0$.

**Goal:** Ultimately, I want to find which coefficients of the form $C_{i,0}=C_{0,i}$ are potentially nontrivial.

**Observations:** Note that for arbitrary $i$, coefficients of the form $C_{i,0}$ will appear in \eqref{relation} whenever $m+n=i$.  i.e., for a given $i$, relation \eqref{relation} implies $(n+m)$ homogeneous equations involving $C_{i,0}$---recall $n\ge 0$ and $m>0$.

For example, when $i=4$, relation \eqref{relation} implies

\begin{align}
C_{4,0}+C_{3,1} &= 0\\
C_{4,0}+2C_{3,1}+C_{2,2} &=0\\
C_{4,0}+4C_{3,1}+3C_{2,2} &=0\\
2C_{4,0}+8C_{3,1}+6C_{2,2} &=0 \tag{**}\label{i=4}\\
\end{align}

Clearly, the last two relations in \eqref{i=4} are not linearly independent.  Hence, we have 3 relations with 4 unknowns.  They are solved by

\begin{align}
C_{4,0}=C_{2,2}=-C_{3,1}.
\end{align}

That is, $C_{4,0}$ can be nonzero (and chosen independently of all other $C_{i,0}$).

**Obs. 1:**  I have worked out the system of equations corresponding to many different $i$ values.  For a given $i$, I always find there are only $(i-1)$ linearly independent relations.  That is, the $(n,m)=(0,i),(1,i-1)$ relations are always linearly dependent--and, in fact, related by a multiple of 2.

**Obs. 2:** In all cases considered, I find $C_{i,0}$ can be made to satisfy the relations of \eqref{relation} for $i$ even but must be zero for $i$ odd.  e.g.,
\begin{align}
C_{1,0}&=0\\
C_{2,0}&=-C_{1,1}\\
C_{3,0}&=C_{2,1}=0\\
C_{4,0}&=C_{2,2}=-C_{3,1}\\
C_{5,0}&=C_{4,1}=C_{3,2}=0\\
\vdots
\end{align}

**Question:** How can one show these observations hold for all $i\in \mathbb{Z}^+$?

**Update:** Proof of Obs. 1. It is useful to note that for $(n,m)=(1,i-1)$ the LHS of \eqref{relation} can be expressed,

\begin{align}
\sum_{j\le i-1} \frac{(i-1)!}{j!(i-1-j)!}C_{1+j,i-1-j}&=\sum_{1\le j+1\le i} \frac{(i-1)!}{j!(i-1-j)!}C_{1+j,i-1-j}\\
&=\sum_{1\le l \le i} \frac{(i-1)!}{(l-1)!(i-l)!}C_{l,i-l}\\
&=\sum_{0\le l \le i} \frac{l}{i}\frac{i!}{l!(i-l)!}C_{l,i-l},\\
\end{align}
where I defined a new summation index in the second line $l\equiv j+1$.

Showing linear dependence of the $(n,m)=(0,i)$ relation on the $(n,m)=(1,i-1)$ relation then requires me to show

\begin{align}\sum_{j\le i} \frac{i!}{j!(i-j)!}C_{j,i-j}\propto \sum_{l \le i} \frac{l}{i}\frac{i!}{l!(i-l)!}C_{l,i-l}. \tag{***}\label{propto}
\end{align}

The symmetry in the coefficients now allows me to write the LHS of \eqref{propto} as

\begin{align}
\sum_{j\le i} \frac{i!}{j!(i-j)!}C_{j,i-j}&=\sum_{j\le \lfloor i/2\rfloor} \left[ \frac{i!}{j!(i-j)!}+\frac{i!}{(i-j)!j!}\right] C_{j,i-j}\\
&=2\sum_{j\le \lfloor i/2 \rfloor }\frac{i!}{j!(i-j)!}C_{j,i-j}.
\end{align}

Likewise, symmetry in the coefficients on the RHS of \eqref{propto} implies

\begin{align}
\sum_{l \le i} \frac{l}{i}\frac{i!}{l!(i-l)!}C_{l,i-l}&=\sum_{l \le \lfloor i/2 \rfloor} \left[ \frac{l}{i}\frac{i!}{l!(i-l)!}+\frac{i-l}{i}\frac{i!}{(i-l)!l!} \right]C_{l,i-l}\\
&=\sum_{l\le \lfloor i/2 \rfloor} \frac{i!}{l!(i-l)!}C_{l,i-l}.
\end{align}

This establishes Obs. 1 in the general case. $\blacksquare$

Only Obs. 2 remains to be shown!